# Ceiling strapping over plaster

Tags: drywall, framing

I have old plaster walls that are not in the best shape. I want to strap them with 1x3 or 1x4 and will screw right into the joists. Would that be enough for me to run conduit in between the strapping? Also has anyone ran copper plumbing in between the strapping?

Comment: Your title mentions ceilings and your post refers to walls. Please revise to be more accurate and to make your title a specific question. See [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: 1x wood (~ 3/4") is going to be pretty tight for conduit and/or plumbing. 2x wood might work better.

Answer (score 1):

**No**.  If you are planning to run new electrical and plumbing behind a new ceiling you should remove the old ceiling.  Running electrical and plumbing in a 3/4 inch space behind a false ceiling will create a LOT of problems, and you'll be creating dangerous, hacky laborious solutions.   If it was minimal, you just need to run one cable or provision for one ceiling pendant, you could work around it.  But if you're installing lots of new utilities you'll regret it.

Comment: Thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

The 1x strapping allows for electric cable and 1/2" copper,CPVC, or PEX. Conduit may be tight, but you could scrape away some of the old plaster, ( it's being covered anyway) and imbed the conduit so it doesn't bulge the new drywall.

This is done in homes built in Fla. often where the 1x is installed over solid polyisocyanurate insulation on the inside of exterior block walls.

There are [Stand off straps](https://www.parts-express.com/Arlington-CS7-Plastic-Cable-Standoff-261-4268?quantity=1&utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=19344435533&utm_content=144470248733&gadid=642323859525&gclid=CjwKCAjwp6CkBhB_EiwAlQVyxaHPX6g5UTqnqLawcnEigg14L_3h7Nof_db3yvOg9G1PvQvprHi-ZRoCd7YQAvD_BwE) to hold the cable away from the 1x or furring strips.

For the ceiling, just run utilities in the attic, or open the space needed for cable and plumbing.  More detail from you would get a more specific answer.

Comment: Thanks. For the help. It's maybe best for me to just punch holes in the old plaster and just strapping to over the plaster so i don't have to patch anything?

Comment: You would be best served to add the details to your original post, with some pics. That way we know more precisely what you are dealing with and trying to accomplish.